# Java found start positions between tags

Tags: java

this below code can find text which are between tags such as `<tag></tag>`
but i'm trying to find start and end positions for found texts, for example this code result is:

```
[apple, orange, pear]
```

instead of this result i want to have this result:

```
[5,9],   //apple
[33,38], //orange
[44,47], //pear
```

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String str = "<tag>apple</tag><b>hello</b><tag>orange</tag><tag>pear</tag>";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(str).toArray()));
}

private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<tag>(.+?)</tag>");

private static List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
    final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return tagValues;
}
```

how can i find start position of texts on this part of code:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
        tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Do not use regex to parse XML, use Java's XML parsing infrastructure.

Comment: @tux-world its a bad practice to use regex for this kind of parsing, use XML parsing it is very easy and fundamental concept of java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use formal parser, You can modify your code

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    //tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start(1));
    System.out.println(" End index: " + matcher.end(1));
    tagValues.add(String.format("[%d,%d]", matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)));
}
```

Comment: @tux-world it is workable but you need to avoid using regex when working with tags

Answer (score 1):

Since this a tag based input like `xml` you can use `SAX` parsing or `dom` parsing techniques .

```
File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
Document document = saxBuilder.build(inputFile);
getAttribute("tag");
```

See full details [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_jdom_parse_document.htm)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String str = "<tag>apple</tag><b>hello</b><tag>orange</tag><tag>pear</tag>";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(str).toArray()));
}

private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<tag>(.+?)</tag>");

private static List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
    final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String found = matcher.group(1);

        int start = str.indexOf(found);
        tagValues.add("[" + String.valueOf(start) + ", " + String.valueOf(start + found.length()) + "]");
    }
    return tagValues;
}
```